# LG K120 - removing frp with fastboot

Tags: factory-reset, fastboot, lg

I found a LG K120 (LG Spree in US,LG K4 in Europe), after wiping it, in the setup process it asks me for the previous google acount (FRP).

After searching a lot of this model, none of the bypass google account solutions are valid.

I am trying now reinstalling the whole operating system via fastboot, but as the model is very new, there is no implementation (or at least, I'm not able to find it).

The only solution that comes to me is to wipe the frp partion, in HTC is located in /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/frp, but I don't know which of the listed below is related with frp.

```
#fastboot getvar all

(bootloader)    max-download-size: 0x8000000
(bootloader)    partition-size:flashinfo: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:flashinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:userdata: 32000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:userdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:cache: c800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:cache: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:system: 9a000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:system: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvdata: 2100000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:efuse: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:efuse: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:persist: 3000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:persist: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:factory: 1400000   
(bootloader)    partition-type:factory: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:rct: 100000
(bootloader)    partition-type:rct: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:cust: 6400000
(bootloader)    partition-type:cust: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lgfota: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lgfota: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:persistent: 200000
(bootloader)    partition-type:persistent: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:mpt: 1600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:mpt: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:persist_lg: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:persist_lg: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:encrypt: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:encrypt: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:eksst: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:eksst: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee2: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee2: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee1: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee1: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:keystore: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:keystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:secro: 600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:secro: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:oemkeystore: 200000
(bootloader)    partition-type:oemkeystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:seccfg: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:seccfg: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:expdb: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:expdb: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lo_bak_go: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lo_bak_go: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:logo: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:logo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:recovery: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:recovery: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:boot: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:boot: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:para: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:para: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:laf: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:laf: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lkbak: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lkbak: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lk: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lk: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect2: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect2: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect1: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect1: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvram: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvram: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:ftm: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:ftm: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:misc2: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:misc2: raw data     
(bootloader)    partition-size:proinfo: 300000
(bootloader)    partition-type:proinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:preloader: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:preloader: raw data
(bootloader)    warranty: no
(bootloader)    unlocked: yes
(bootloader)    secure: no
(bootloader)    kernel: lk
(bootloader)    product: MUSE6735M_E1LTE_L
(bootloader)    version: 0.5
all: Done!!
finished. total time: 0.013s
```

¿Can anyone give me an idea?

Another problem than I am facing is when trying to erase a partition y get the following.

```
# fastboot erase cache
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'cache'...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.002s
```

And the same answer with many other commands, it seems that LG has implemented a very reduced set of fastboot protocol commands.

To overcome this, flashing the partition with zero's file can do de job, that is my guess.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried wiping and restoring the partition table?

Comment: Did you try [THIS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/general/tut-bypass-lg-lock-google-account-t3223518) guide from XDA Developers? Or you'll need a tool named Z3X Box LG Activation (Paid tool)

Comment: Does not work for LG K120

Comment: Can you point to some relatet tutorial or extend your answer. Basically, I don't know how to wipe and restore the partition table.

Comment: But this tool works for your phone model. you'll meed to flash the phone and use the above mentioned tool to remove the FRP

Comment: Thanks, but the tool costs more than the mobile, and it is por personal use.